# Database designing - for vehicles application

Tags: mysql, database, erd

I am trying to build vehicle application but I am confused about the table structure currently I have created those tables according to tire specifications. Would you check out the design structure and correct me if something missing. ERD Diagram uploaded with more explanation about the diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split the "ty_tires" table into two separate tables:

- "ty_model" - for tyre model
- "ty_version" - for a version of a    particular model

The ty_model table would need to have a many-to-one relationship with ty_season, ty_brand and ty_version. The ty_version table would need to have a many-to-one relationship  with ty_width, ty_profile, ty_diameter, ty_speed, ty_load.

Comment: Thanks #Venc for your help. i will do the design right now and i will upload it.

Comment: Venc i just upload the second erd. would you check it out.

Comment: Where is the ERD?